# Photograph of Marjorie Rice

Tags: mathematicians

I'm giving a presentation this weekend about Marjorie Rice's work on tilings. The only photograph I have of her (from her website) is small and pixelated, and I haven't been able to make contact with her to ask her for a better one. I'd be most grateful if you could point me to a better photo of her, either on the web or in print or from your personal archives.

Thanks!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff : what part of the FAQ do you think speaks against this?  This is (essentially) a reference question about the history of mathematics; it's a practical, answerable question based on an actual problem the user faces.

Comment: You should use my [Pentagon Tilings](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PentagonTilings/) demonstration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat spurious [website](http://www.writeopinions.com/marjorie-rice) that nonetheless purports to have three pictures of her, one of which is the one you have.  If you click on them you get higher resolution.

Also, this doesn't answer your question directly, being of low resolution, but [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_YPQpf9Cok&t=31m50s) is a video about her, including an interview.

Comment: That video is awesome! Thanks for sharing it. I ended up grabbing a snapshot from it for my presentation--it was high res enough for my purposes. And I look forward to sharing the video with my students!

Answer (score 7):

See [Marjorie Rice, page 2](http://www.redmond.k12.or.us/14552011718214563/lib/14552011718214563/Lesson_7.5.pdf) from a newsletter published by Key Curriculum Press, on Tesselations. There's a photo of Marjorie Rice (on the left), at the lower left of page 2 of the newsletter. The link will take you to the pdf.

I don't know if this is an improvement over your current picture, but I thought I'd post this, in case it helps. Here's an image of page 2 of the pdf:

[image]

Comment: Very nice pointers +1, also check out this nice feature on [*google*](https://www.google.com/search?q=images+of+Marjorie+Rice+tilings&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=MNt5UeP7M6_nigKT0oCgBA&ved=0CDEQsAQ&biw=1392&bih=735)

Comment: That's a great find, and it was a good option for me to have for my presentation. Ultimately I went with something else, but thanks for sharing it!

Comment: You're welcome, Justin! Wish I could have been of greater help!